# React Dropzone: Image files preview issue

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I upload image file with previewing it in react dropzone. However, after uploading, the file is successfully uploaded (I can see it in console) but sometimes the image file is previewed and sometimes the same image file give error like:

**GET blob:http://localhost:3000/438716d3-2317-438b-9d1e-eb7bc5e6149f net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwjI9.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the solution was to use URL.createObjectURL in the image src when displaying the image file from Dropzone.
e.g

```
<img src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} alt={file.name} />
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.